# React Input Element Not Updating When Updating Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a React version of [this](http://arocketman.github.io/Town-Of-Salem-Helping-Tool/).

You can see what I have so far on [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/MatthewMob/pen/dNxLvp).

The issue here is that when you type into a text field (under the "Suspected Player" column) and then click the adjacent name (under the "Role" column) to remove that row, the text persists inside the input, and is then adjacent to a different name.
The expected behavior is that you'd click the name to remove the row and both the elements (the name and text input) would disappear.

All the items in the table are stored in an array called `checklist` in the state of the `RoleList` class.

The component for each list item in the table is this:

```
class RoleCheckpoint extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        };
    }

    deleteThis() {
        this.props.removeRole(this.props.role.id);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            text: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);

        return (
            <tr>
                <td className="vertAlign remove noselect" onClick={this.deleteThis.bind(this)}>
                    {this.props.role.el}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" spellCheck="false" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.text} />
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

When you click on the name it invokes the components `deleteThis` function, which in turn invokes `RoleList`'s `removeRole` function (that goes through the array of list items, and removes the one with the matching ID from the components state), which is being passed as a prop to `RoleCheckpoint`.

I've tried using `this.forceUpdate()` in the `deleteThis` function, and as you can see I've tried binding the input field's `value` to the components state (called `text`), yet still the input doesn't update when removing the component from the DOM.

Any help is appreciated, if you need more clarification I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A "key" is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

```
<RoleCheckpoint role={role} key={role.id} removeRole={this.removeRole.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is typical when you have a list of components and you have not set the key of the objects correctly. It need to be something that identifies the object.
Probably you can use the name field:

```
<RoleCheckpoint key={role.name} .../>
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html